# Have username instead of id then nested route /users/:id/nest_routes to /username/nested_routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello i have heaps of routes such as the following

```
  resources :users do
    resources :shipping_methods, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    resources :cart_items, only: [:create, :index, :destroy]
    resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
    resources :addresses, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  end
```

They all produce the following route

`/users/:id/nested_route`

For instance an edit shipping method view produces the following

`/users/1/shipping_methods/11/edit`

**How do i make all these routes produce this:**

`/username/nested_route`

**For example the edit shipping method view above should produce the following:**

`/username/shipping_methods/11/edit`

Comment: If you have a `current_user` method then create a custom route that doesn't use the GET `:id` param and instead use `current_user.id` to find the users shipping_methods.

Comment: Another way is to use a gem for pretty URL's, like [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Answer (score 2):

It's one of way to do this. Override `path` for `users` resource and use `collection` for sub resources. It gives you path `/:user_id/shipping_methods/new`

```
resources :users, path: ':user_id' do
  collection do
    resources :shipping_methods, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    resources :cart_items, only: [:create, :index, :destroy]
    resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
    resources :addresses, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  end
end
```

Override `to_param` method for `User` model to use `username` instead of `id` in router

```
def to_param
  self.username.parameterize
end
```

To find user in sub-router use `User.find_by(username: params[:user_id]`